# HAML - if / elsif construction

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement, haml

I need this construction in my HAML code:

```
- if something1
  %div.a
- elsif something2
  %div.b
- elsif something3
  %div.c
- else
  %div.d
    %div another content
```

I would expected I get something like:

```
<div class="a|b|c|d">
  <div>another content</div>
</div>
```

But in the fact I get

```
   <div class="a|b|c|d"></div>
   <div>another content</div>
```

How I must to update my code, if I need to get:

another content

?

Comment: shouldn't be an indent after else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you should create a helper method instead:

```
%div{:class => helper_method(useful_parameters)}
```

The really ugly way to accomplish this is with ternary operators `(condition ? true_case : false_case)` which doesn't sound like a good solution given from the fact that you selected haml and want to have your code base clean.

Comment: I think that when the OP write `a|b|c|d` he means he wants either a, b, c OR d, not all of them at once, but your answer still applies.

Comment: @Deleteman On second thought I think you're right. I removed the remark as it adds no value.

Comment: This is what I've been looking for :)

Comment: do i need to define the helper_method in the model or the controller?

Answer (score 10):

@Ingenu's helper method looks like the smarter approach, but if you don't mind it quicker and dirtier, you could do:

```
- if something1
  -divclass = 'a'
- elsif something2
  -divclass = 'b'
- elsif something3
  -divclass = 'c'
- else
  -divclass = 'd'
%div{:class => divclass}
  %div another content
```

Comment: Good one as well! Thanks for idea!

Comment: fyi: if you only want to include a class in a certain case and nothing in other cases you can just return `nil` and the attribute will not be set, instead of setting `class=""`

Answer (score 0):

You could extend your if condition with this module and then use smalltalk-style conditions

```
  module IfTrue
    def ifTrue &block
      yield if self
      slf=self
      o = Object.new
      def o.elseIf val, &block
         yield if !slf && val
      end
    end
  end
```

now you could code stuff like this:

```
  condition.extend(IfTrue).ifTrue{ 
   do_stuff 
  }elseIf(condition2){
    doOtherStuff
  }
```

or, if you are a naughty monkey patcher ;-):

```
 Object.include IfTrue

 condition.ifTrue{ 
    do_stuff 
 }elseIf(condition2){
    doOtherStuff
 }
```

if you want to chain more than one elseif you will have to adapt this code by somehow factoring the elsif definition